Lavarel error passing data to blade - undefined variable
I'm discovering Laravel with a little project with Breeze to manage authentication. As I'm completely new, I'm dealing with a basic problem to simply display data on the dashbord.
Here is my code. The dashboard is displayed to authenticated users.
Route from 'routes' folder :
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MessagesController;
use App\Models\Message;

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard', [MessageController::class, 'index']);
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

The controller from app/Http/Controllers:
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Message;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */    
     
    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::all();
        return view('dashboard',compact('messages'));
    }
(...)
}

And the dashboard from resources/views (main extract)  :
<div class="w-5/6 py-10">
    @foreach ($messages as $message)
    <div class="m-auto">
        <h3 class="text-gray-700 text-5xl">
        De : {{$message->id_user}}
        </h3>
        <p class="text-lg text-gray-700 py-6">
        {{$message->comment}}
        </p>
        <span class="uppercase text-blue-500 font-bold text -xs italic">
        {{$message->created_at}}
        </span>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

I've checked the doc and several tuto / videos, I found several possible syntax to pass an array from de controller, but none of the syntax I tested worked for me, the $message variable in unknown.
Do I have to manage something with the middleware? Or does it come from another part?
Thank you for your help.

Looks like you have a typo on line 7 of your routes file. MessageController::class should be MessagesController::class

Oups, Thank you @kylepg, you're right. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. In fact, I'm afraid I've made several errors like this, running php artisan, because I'm still confused about the logical use of singular & plural for views, controllers, and so on... in the filenames and in the syntax inside them. etc... Is it right to correct by hand a name file, or should I use php artisan to remove the file, then recreate it with the correct spelling ? Thank you

change your code to
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MessagesController;

Route::get('/dashboard', [MessagesController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])
    ->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

===========================
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Message;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::all();
        return view('dashboard', compact('messages'));
    }
}

=====================
 <div class="w-5/6 py-10">
    @foreach ($messages as $message)
    <div class="m-auto">
        <h3 class="text-gray-700 text-5xl">
        De : {{$message->id_user}}
        </h3>
        <p class="text-lg text-gray-700 py-6">
        {{$message->comment}}
        </p>
        <span class="uppercase text-blue-500 font-bold text-xs italic">
        {{$message->created_at}}
        </span>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>


Why?  What did you change?  Explain your answer, educate OP and all future visitors what was wrong and how you fixed it.

The Laravel docs are the best resource if you're not sure how to do something.  How to pass data to a view, for example, is shown in under Passing Data to Views:

... you may pass an array of data to views to make that data available to the view:
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);


From that example we can see that the closure in your routes file:
return view('dashboard', [MessageController::class, 'index']);

Is actually attempting to pass a variable named $MessageController::class, with value index, to your view.  That probably doesn't work, bcs of the meta-characters in the variable name.  There certainly is no variable named $messages, and your controller method is not even being called.
There's a simple example at the top of the Laravel Routes documentation showing how to call a controller method for a route:
Route::get('/dashboard', [MessageController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])
    ->name('dashboard');

